# How to use object child as value in select without matching property name

Tags: html, angular

I want to set value of select field to the one specified in `repairData` property called `reportShiftId`, but it doesn't work. On the other hand if i make Shift object inside `repairData` and reference it with `reportShift.id` it works.

In not working code when i change `repairData.reportShiftId` which is ng model of select, select option does not change, but after i choose something manually in select, ngModel starts working properly.

**Not working code:**

```
export class RepairData {
    reportShiftId: number;
    ...
}
```

-

```
<select class="form-control" name="shift" [(ngModel)]="repairData.reportShiftId">
      <option *ngFor="let shift of shifts" [ngValue]="shift.id">{{shift.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**Working code:**

```
export class RepairData {
    reportShift: Shift;
    ...
}
```

-

```
<select class="form-control" name="shift" [(ngModel)]="repairData.reportShift.id">
      <option *ngFor="let shift of shifts" [ngValue]="shift.id">{{shift.name}}</option>
</select>
```

How to use `reportShiftId`(number) instead of `reportShift.id`(Shift.number)?

Comment: is ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush applied to the component, which template is demonstrated in the question?

Comment: Im new to angular. i think it isn't. it's just a normal component generated by visual studio code plugin "Angular Files".

Comment: the cause of the problem isn't provided. I was just tried to guess what is wrong. is there a ChangeDetectionStrategy code piece in the component.ts file?

Comment: it whould be inside of @Component({... here... }) configuration. if yes - try removing it. should help your problem

Comment: No, it only has selector, templateUrl and styleUrls i never changed @component{} in any component.

Comment: Can you show how you change the value of reportShiftId, or even better a stackblitz?

Comment: Normally i want to set value from service, but even setting `repairData.reportShiftId = 2` in ngOnInit or on button click doesn't work.

Comment: I take shifts from API and i don't know how to emulate that request on stackblitz.

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement an compareWith function like so :

```
<select class="form-control" name="shift" [compareWith]="compareWithFunction" [(ngModel)]="repairData.reportShiftId">
      <option *ngFor="let shift of shifts" [ngValue]="shift.id">{{shift.name}}</option>
</select>

 compareWithFunction(item1,item2){
   return item1 && item2 ? item1.id === item2.id : item1 === item2;
  }
```

Comment: Check this stackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-afr8kd

Comment: changing default compareWith function to something custom is helpfull if i want to implement select for whole model instead of just Id.

Comment: On stackblitz it works, but if i paste it to my app it doesn't but i figured out how to make it work.

Comment: I’m glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

I know what the problem was. 
After i changed `name` html attribute from **shift** to **reportShift** (the same name as object property) it started working.

Actually i think i had more than one select with the same `name` so that could be the problem.